# How to update the table depending upon the dates in laravel query builder or sql

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am facing issue in updating records in table. My user_plans table look like below:

```
id  remaning_images transaction_id  user_id   start_date      expiry_date   status  
 1  100               100             1       2018-09-22      2019-09-22    Active
 2  50                101             2       2018-10-20      2019-10-20    Active
 3  50                102             3       2018-10-21      2019-10-21    Active
 4  50                103             4       2018-10-19      2019-10-19    Active
```

I want to update the `remaning_images` column to `250` and it will update when 30 days done See example below:

- My 1st record start date is **sept 22 2018**
- When **22nd oct 2018** comes, I want to update remanaing images column to `250`
- When **22nd Nov 2018** will come again column will update to `250`. it will work till `expiry_date` column as mentioned.
- And same behavior will work for other transactions.

I want to do this thing with `sql` query or laravel query builder.

I have actually done with php with getting all plans and update one by one. But i think that would not work if my transactions are in hundreds of thousands or in millions.

So i want to run using sql query.  I am not sure may be it will done using Case statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't tested, but it should be something like this:

```
UPDATE user_plans 
SET remaning_images = 250 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(start_date,'%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d') 
AND (NOW() BETWEEN start_date AND expiry_date)
```

First WHERE condition checks if current month day is the same day as of start_date, second condition checks if current date is between your start_date and end_date. All you need to do now is to run cron job for this query.

Comment: it will work on on every month of 22nd? according to start_date